# SharePoint Modern List view threshold error for Some users

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, modern-experience, 2019

I have migrated the SharePoint list (Exceeds threshold limit) from MOSS 2007 to SP 2019 using ShareGate tool. When I open that list using User A (Same permission as User B) account the List was rendering without any issue but when I open that same list using User B, it show "Something went wrong. List exceeds threshold limit"

**Check List**

1. Same List View.
2. List Permission
3. List View filters
4. Indexed Columns (Same as source)
5. Does not have any view filter like [Me]

Can anyone help to find out the issue

Answer (score 1):

@Shahul Hameed

@Jimas has suggested a good solution for testing an upper boundary, but in ***addition*** to his well-informed and detailed suggestion, I also Believe you should test the lower boundary of your list threshold issue.

I have encountered this very issue myself, on-prem - with a different version of SharePoint some years ago.  It had nothing to do with the migration, from what I could tell.

**Instructions**
*Do all of this in a replica of the original list using ShareGate to create an exact copy of the original MOSS 2007 list.*

Change the view’s configuration as such:

1. Change the Item Limit to 30, if it is not already set to 30, *and*
2. Ensure that the option to ‘display in batches of this size’ is selected.

If that does not Fix, try this solution , which has worked for me in the past:

3. Next, delete all views other than the default view.
4. Create a new view - do not make ***any*** changes to the new view, just save it.
5. Make the newly created view the default view & delete the previous default view.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, exceeding the list view threshold means, basically, 2 things.

1. that the results are more that the list view threshold
2. that sharepoint takes a long running query to iterate over a large dataset, which transaltes in time consuming queries and if the entries are over a limit, SQL Server might enforce a lock on the table.

These are the basic causes that might throw the above exception.
In order to solve the problem you can

1. raise the limit, since its an on-premise installation (not recommended, because other problems will start occuring, but you can use this method just to see if it works)
2. enforce filters and **filter based on indexed columns**.

In general, it is good practise to audit the SQL server with extended events in order to understand the problem. This method will give you a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jimas13. But the list was showing without any issue for User A. Only problem for User B.

Comment: Are the users members of the same SharePoint group?

Comment: Yes, both have contributes permission

Comment: theres also a list item permission which someone can set on the item and not list level. Have you checked that both users have the same permissions on all list items? Have you tried creating an filtered view on an indexed column?

Comment: SQL server extended events can point out the problem that is being generated when the problematic user is trying to iterate over the list. Also, aren't the splogs mentioning anything?

Comment: @shahul hameed
Does this difference between the the two accounts *always* happen, or just during work hours, when there is load on your system?

Comment: The users who are able to see the items in the view have SCA access?